# Trying to webscrape soundcloud with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

I am trying to **scrape** soundcloud and other music platforms for data but I seem to be stuck at soundcloud because I get None, AttributeError or [], but when I trying **scraping** a regular website(non music). I get the data. what am I doing wrong please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')
song = soup.find('li', class_='soundList__item')
print(song)
```

this code returns this.

```
None or AttributeError.
```

Comment: The songs are probably fetched dynamically through javascript. Take a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in order to deal with javascript.

Comment: add a user-agent to your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the raw output (variable soup from your code).

This code extract raw songs title:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
song = soup.find_all('h2', itemprop='name')
print(song)
```

An example of an item from the output list of the code above:

```
<h2 itemprop="name"><a href="/jujubucks/squad-too-deep-ft-cool-prince" itemprop="url">Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)</a>
```

But without selenium or scrapy, you can't scrape all data from this website, they use dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but since I want the other data as well, like plays and posted date. I guess I'll have to use selenium.